# My background image won't show up in blender 2.79

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

as you can see there is nothing there even though I am in top view

[image]

Comment: It maybe the image file type you are using is not compatible. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/media/image_formats.html

Comment: You are using prespective view, background images show only in othogonal preset views and in camera view. Press numpad 5 to switch to orthogonal view.

Comment: What happens if you click on the "Color Space" dropdown in the background settings there? It *should* be "sRGB" yours is blank, so I'm guessing that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the top left corner, you are in the top and perspective view (Top Persp). Use the menu View>View Persp/Ortho, to switch to orthographic view. Or use the shortcut "Numpad 5".